# nginix with keycloak : There was an error while logging in: request to the redirect_uri_path but there's no session state found

Tags: keycloak, nginx-reverse-proxy

We are using keycloak with nginix to authenticate the application behind nginix.
We are facing the following error while trying to access it from another application which is keycloak enabled.

"There was an error while logging in: request to the redirect_uri_path but there's no session state found".

Similar error is encountered while trying to access the application directly from the browser in FF
"There was an error while logging in: state from argument: 820fc50551b9a3652a0aaa51e2d56b3e does not match state restored from session: 4773cd915128f60e17bfd0d6e2b61fd2"

Answer (score 0):

This answer will be to late for OP, however if you're getting this issue intermittently, I found that setting"worker_processes 1" in the nginx config fixed the problem for me.  Apparently concurrent requests were confusing things.

https://github.com/zmartzone/lua-resty-openidc/issues/206